# Coluna para linha MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

> ```
>     |    Roll No   | Student Name |   Q1   |  Q2  |  Q3  |
>     |--------------|--------------|--------|------|------|
>     |            1 |      Aluno 1 |      1 |    1 |    1 |
>     |            2 |      Aluno 2 |      1 |    1 |    0 |
>     |            3 |      Aluno 3 |      1 |    1 |    1 |
> ```

Gostaria de uma consulta que me trouxesse o seguinte resultado, já tentei mas não consegui:

> ```
> | Roll No | Student Name | Nota | idquestion |
> |---------|--------------|------|------------|
> |       1 |      Aluno 1 |    1 |     Q1     |
> |       1 |      Aluno 1 |    1 |     Q2     |
> |       1 |      Aluno 1 |    1 |     Q3     |
>
> |       2 |      Aluno 2 |    1 |     Q1     |
> |       2 |      Aluno 2 |    1 |     Q2     |
> |       2 |      Aluno 2 |    0 |     Q3     |
>
> |       3 |      Aluno 3 |    1 |     Q1     |
> |       3 |      Aluno 3 |    1 |     Q2     |
> |       3 |      Aluno 3 |    1 |     Q3     |
> ```

Exemplo no sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe0f85/1/0

Comment: dei uma modificada na resposta, acredito que possa ajudar ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa é dividir a consulta em três *subselects*, um para cada `idquestion`; o "problema" é que serão várias consultas, caso o banco seja muito grande, pode ficar pesada.

```
select `Roll No`, `Student Name`, `Nota`, `idquestion` from (
  select `Roll No`, `Student Name`, `Q. 1` as `Nota`, 'Q. 1' as `idquestion` from `TABLE`
  union all
  select `Roll No`, `Student Name`, `Q. 2` as `Nota`, 'Q. 2' as `idquestion` from `TABLE`
  union all
  select `Roll No`, `Student Name`, `Q. 3` as `Nota`, 'Q. 3' as `idquestion` from `TABLE`) as tabela
order by `Roll No`, `idquestion`
```

detalhe: caso tenha mais notas, seria(m) necessário(s) mais *subselect(s)*. [**Exemplo no *fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe0f85/11)

---

> **editado - forma genérica**

Resolvi ir atrás de um código mais genérico. Segui a seguinte lógica:

1. criei tabelas temporárias para armazenar os nomes das colunas;
2. para cada das colunas, será consultado e inserido em outra tabela temporária os dados de cada usuário referentes à nota da prova específica;
3. por fim, consulta da tabela de dados, ordenando por usuário e etapa.

Abaixo botei o código mas acho mais fácil entender/exemplificar [neste fiddle](https://rextester.com/JJHXA32759). Acredito que assim podes fazer a consulta independente da quantidade de colunas, sem precisar dos mil *unions*.

```
create table `tabela_colunas` (`id` int, `coluna` varchar(100));

SET @row_number := 0;
INSERT INTO tabela_colunas (id, coluna)
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS id, column_name as 'coluna' FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE' AND column_name like 'Q.%'; -- aqui segui a lógica do exemplo no seu fiddle

CREATE TABLE `table_tmp` (
  `Roll No` int(10),
  `Student Name` varchar(39),
  `Nota` int(1),
  `idquestion` varchar(10));
SET @id_tabela:=1, @total:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela_colunas);

WHILE @id_tabela <= @total DO
    set @sql := concat(
       'insert into table_tmp (`Roll No`, `Student Name`, `Nota`, `idquestion`) select `Roll No`, `Student Name`, `',
       (SELECT coluna FROM tabela_colunas WHERE id = @id_tabela), '` as Nota, \'',
       (SELECT coluna FROM tabela_colunas WHERE id = @id_tabela), '\' as idquestion', ' from `table`');

    PREPARE myquery FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE myquery;

    SET @id_tabela = @id_tabela + 1;    
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM table_tmp ORDER BY `Roll No`, `idquestion`;
```

Comment: Infelizmente falta um equivalente ao comando `UNPIVOT` no MySQL. Para um problema mais genérico em que `Q1...QN` não são conhecidos de antemão o *workaround* costuma envolver a geração dinâmica de cláusulas `UNION ALL`. Exemplo no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16359654/664577

Comment: Muito show cara!